# JQUERY BIND to a LABEL, and pass the name & value

Tags: jquery, binding, input, click

```
<p id="noteTypebox">
<label for="noteType_2" class="notetypelabel" id="noteType_2" >
<input type="radio" name="noteTypeID" value="2" class="notetype">IDI</input>
</label>
</p>
```

Given the code above, I would like JQUERY code that Binds to the LABEL, since the INPUT box is hidden (I don't want the radio buttons on the apge).

When a user clicks on a label, it should trigger the JQUERY function and provide the value of the INPUT associated with the label. For example, if a user clicked on label for="noteType_1", it would be able to alert noteType_1 & 1

Here is my current code, I could use your help! thanks

```
$( document ).ready( function() { 
    $('#noteTypebox:label').click(radioClicks)
});

function radioClicks() {
    alert(input name + input value);
    return false;
};
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would do something like this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
    $('#noteTypebox label').click(radioClicks);
});

function radioClicks() {
    var input = $(this).children("input");
    alert(input.attr("name") + " " + input.val());
    return false;
};
```

This however relies that you always structure your HTML the same.

A far more robust way would be to do the following:

```
function radioClicks() {
    var label = $(this);
    var input = $("input#" + label.attr("for"));
    alert(input.attr("name") + " " + input.val());
    return false;
};
```

in this case the label can be anywhere in relation to the input and it will still work.

UPDATE: Have updated second code snippet to only get the radio button that is checked.

### A response to the comment:

The code above looks for an `input` with the same id as the `for` attribute of the `label`. Seeing as you changed the id of the `input`, this breaks the code and makes the second example not so adequate. The first example however should work fine for you as long as the `input` remains a child of the `label`. Also, I need to mention that the `for` attribute on your `label` has become redundant with your changes since all its saying now is that the `label` applies to itself.

Comment: Both of his inputs have the same `name`.

Comment: Ran into an issue and needed to change the HTML to:

<label for="noteType_2" class="notetypelabel" id="noteType_2"> <input type="radio" name="noteTypeID" value="2" class="notetype">IDI</input></label>

This ended up breaking the JS. 

By updating the 3rd line to:
 var input = $("label#" + label.attr("for"));
I received the NAME but am no longer getting the INPUT's value, can you help me update the JS to return the VALUE, likely, replacing "input.val()"

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You need to find the `input` element associated with the `label`, like this:

```
var input = $('#' + $(this).attr('for'));
```

You can then get the name by writing `input.attr('name')` and the value by writing `input.val()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just change to:

```
$(".notetypelabel").click( ....
```

Comment: But how do I get the NAME  & VALUE